# Virtual Keyboard and resize event

Tags: jquery, keyboard, resize, window-resize

1- I have a dropdown search triggered by a click on a search icon.

```
// Open/Close Search Form and focus in input search field. THIS IS ON DOM READY !
$('.search-trigger').click(function () {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-close', 'icon-search');
    $('.search-dropdown').animate({
        height: 'toggle',
        opacity: 'toggle'
    });
    $('.search-dropdown .search-field').focus();
});
```

2- **On any mobile or tab**, if the icon is clicked the Virtual Keyboard will popup since the `$('.search-dropdown .search-field')` is focused and **the height** of the `$(window)/$(document)` **will change**.

**3- THE ISSUE :**

**A-** If I want to close the dropdown search on resize (when the user **changes the orientation** of the mobile or tab) I can do simply the following :

```
$(window).on('resize', function () { // THE DOM IS READY
    $('.search-trigger .icon-search').removeClass('icon-close');
    $('.search-dropdown').hide();
});
```

But since I know that **the height will change** when the user clicks the icon I can't do **A-** because the dropdown search will be visible for a second and then close back !

**B-** So, to ensure that the dropdown search will be visible I can do the following :

```
// THE DOM IS READY.
var originalWidth = $(window).width();

//CHECK IF THE DROPDOWN SEARCH IS OPENED.
if ($('.icon-close').is(":visible")) {
    $(window).on('resize', function () {

        var newHeight = $(window).height();
        if ($(window).height() === newHeight) {
            $('.search-trigger .icon-search').addClass('icon-close');
            $('.search-dropdown').show();
        }

        if ($(window).width() !== originalWidth) {
            $('.icon-search').removeClass('icon-close');
            $('.search-dropdown').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Now the code will work, the dropdown search will work and if the user changes the orientation the dropdown will be closed. **BUT** since the width is no longer the same as the original one (user has changed the orientation), if the search icon is clicked the dropdown search will be visible for a second and then close back !

So as you can see It's tricky and I've tried a lot of variations...
I've searched a lot and it's time for me to get some help :)

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions :)

Comment: IF ANYONE PASSES BY HERE, I'VE RESOLVED IT. WILL BE POSTING THIS EVENING THE SOLUTION. SYA :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bellow is the full code explained

```
/*
 * Before opening the Header Search Form,
 * do not waste time by creating jQuery object from window multiple times.
 * Do it just once and store it in a variable.
 * This is done to take care of the performance.
 */ 
var $window = $(window);
var originalHeight = $(window).height();
var originalWidth = $(window).width();
//3. Open/Close Header Search Form
$('.search-trigger').click(function () {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-close');
    $('.search-dropdown').animate({
        height: 'toggle',
        opacity: 'toggle'
    });
    // Reset the initial state of the search icon and dropdown
    // Since the height will change when the virtual keybord becomes visible,
    // I don't need to put it inside the resize event and double check it !
    if ($('.icon-close').is(':visible')) {
        if ($window.height() !== originalHeight) {
            $(this).find('i').addClass('icon-close');
            $('.search-dropdown').show();
        }
        $window.resize(function () {
            /* 
             * Do not calculate the new window width twice.
             * Do it just once and store it in a variable.
             */
            var newWidth = $window.width();
            // Do the comparison
            if (originalWidth !== newWidth) {
                // Execute the code
                $('.search-trigger .icon-search').removeClass('icon-close');
                $('.search-dropdown').hide();
                // Reset the width  
                // This is the tricky part that I was misssing :(
                originalWidth = newWidth;
            }
        });
    }
    //  Focus in input search field
    $('.search-dropdown .search-field').focus();
});
// Reset Search Input Value to Search...    
$('input.search-field').val('');
```

Hope this can help someone else in a similar issue.
SYA :)